# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'count' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

Following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBUJVy8phqw

I would like to set up REdux in my Next.js app. But I got stuck. Do not know why. Everything is the same as in the tutorial.

counter.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState: {
    count: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      // Redux Toolkit allows us to write "mutating" logic in reducers. It
      // doesn't actually mutate the state because it uses the Immer library,
      // which detects changes to a "draft state" and produces a brand new
      // immutable state based off those changes
      state.count += 1;
    },
    decrement: (state) => {
      state.count -= 1;
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.count += action.payload;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

store.tsx:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { counterReducer } from "./counter";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
});
```

first part in onboarding2.tsx:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const fallBackLang = "hu";

interface Onboarding2Props {
  lang: string;
  translations: Translation;
}

export default function Onboarding2(props: Onboarding2Props) {
  const { lang, translations } = props;
  const { count } = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have attempted to import 'counterReducer' which is not present in counter.js

'counterReducer' is ought to be the counterSlice.reducer which is exported as default from counter.js

You could simply replace

```
import { counterReducer } from "./counter";
```

with

```
import counterReducer from "./counter";
```

in your store.js file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to add the reducer to the store:

...
reducer: {count: countReducer}
...